XTAL with no output?
I'm troubleshooting a router that is missing WiFi and I figured out it's not seeing MT7915 on PCI bus. The router is using MT7975 (RF frontend) + MT7915 (WiFi) combo. I've started checking usual stuff like power rails, enable signals and clocks. 40MHz clock is missing on both chips so it's likely my issue.
However when I checked XTAL circuit I was surprised to see a standard SMD 2520 XTAL but it's connected in a way that makes no sense to me. XTAL input (pin 1) is connected to MT7975 and all 3 other pins are grounded. The XTAL Out pin from MT7975 connects to clock input pin on MT7915 so I assume both chips share the same clock.
How is it supposed to work when XTAL's output is connected to ground?
I've attached photos from 2 different devices using the same combination of chips and the same XTAL circuit.



"and all 3 other pins are grounded" Have you measured that these pins are connected to ground, or did you only visually inspect the PCB?

Yes I measured it too. I also removed the XTAL and 3 out of 4 pins are definitely grounded. I have no idea how it's supposed to work. This is the first time I'm seeing it.

On the last image, it looks like pin 3 (upper-right) has a via to the left of the pad, which I suspect is not connected to ground.
